# How can i redefine append method in my child class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Implement the `LoggableList` class, inheriting it from the `list` and `Loggable` classes, so that when you add an item to a list using the append method, a message is sent to the log consisting of just the added item.
How can i redefine append method in class `LoggableList` to call log method of `Loggable` class inside append method in `LoggableList` class.

Here is my try to write a code:

```
import time

class Loggable:

    def log(self, msg):
        print(str(time.ctime()) + ": " + str(msg))
        return


class LoggableList(Loggable, list):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = list(input('Please input your massage: '))

    def append(self, element):
        super(LoggableList, self).append(element)
        Loggable.log()
        return
```

Answer (score 2):

0. You can use the shortened version of `super`:

   ```
   super().append(element)
   ```
1. `self.log()`, not `Loggable.log()`.
2. You forgot to provide the argument `msg`.
3. Instead of calling `str` so many times in `Loggable.log`, just use `.format` (or f-string if using Python >= 3.6):

   ```
   print('{}: {}'.format(time.ctime(), msg))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach to subclass built in container types, is to use the abstract base classes provided in the `collections` module:

In the case of list, you should use [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList); it allows you to override special methods that may be difficult otherwise. (see override of `__setitem__` illustrated below).

In this case, you do not need to provide a constructor; the `append` method is overridden to include a call to `self.log(elt)`, prior to calling the `append` method of the superclass.

```
import time
from collections import UserList

class Loggable:
    def log(self, msg):
        print(f'{str(time.ctime())}: {msg}')

        
class LoggableList(UserList, Loggable):
    """A list that documents its successive transformations 
    """

    def append(self, elt):
        self.log(f'append({elt})')
        super().append(elt)
    
    def __setitem__(self, idx, elt):
        self.log(f'set[{idx}] {elt}')
        self.data[idx] = elt
    
        
log_list = LoggableList([1, 2, 3])
log_list.append(4)
log_list[2] = 0
log_list[3] = 'abc'
log_list.append(None)
print(log_list)
```

#### output

```
Fri Nov 13 23:33:33 2020: append(4)
Fri Nov 13 23:33:33 2020: set[2] 0
Fri Nov 13 23:33:33 2020: set[3] abc
Fri Nov 13 23:33:33 2020: append(None)
[1, 2, 0, 'abc', None]
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `super().append()` instead of just doing `self.data.append()`?

Comment: Great question, thank you! `super().append()` is more general, whereas `self.data.append()` relies on the internals (implementation details). (you cannot call `__setitem__` on `super()` (do `super()[idx] = elt`), so I had to use `self.data[idx] = elt` in `__setitem__`)

Comment: Isn't it possible to do `super().__setitem__()`? I thought the use of `self.data` is to avoid the quirky `super` calls (I am asking purely from curiosity as your question made me familiar with `UserList`)